# Can a Progressive Verb Replace "Which"?

Tags: progressive-aspect

Let's say I have the following sentence:

> Yesterday the stock market crashed, which resulted in social collapse.

Is it grammatically correct to change the above sentence to the following form?

> Yesterday the stock market crashed, resulting in social collapse.

If so, what is this progressive substitution called?

Comment: Note that this is not actually a progressive verb: it's called a **present participle**, and it can be used in conjunction with *to be* to form the present progressive/present continuous in English. The present participle conveys an action occurring at the same time as the finite verb (in this case *crashed*) and functions rather like an adjective. Search **participle** on this site, on Wikipedia, or on Google for a greater explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may reword the sentence to use *resulting*, but that's not a progressive "form" (really, tense) of the verb.  It's the present participle.  The progressive forms of the verb *to result* sound a bit odd since a result is a conclusion.  Let's try *to run* for contrasting examples:

Past progressive (main verb):

> Stockbrokers **were running** around in a panic during the stock market crash.

Notice that although it's the present participle, it has formed a past tense verb referring to past time. Of course, it could form a present tense verb, *are running*.

Present participle (modifying *Stockbrokers*):

> Stockbrokers **running** around in a panic caused the stock market crash.

Notice that although it's the present participle, it doesn't refer to present time (or time at all): it describes the state of the brokers.  Presumably, the running around took placing before and during the crash, which is over.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

No, a progressive form (present participle) can never replace *which*. *Which* is elided, not replaced.

Long answer:

It is so called an [**absolute construction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction) (also known as a **participle construction**) or **participle clauses** where a subject is omitted when it is or is considered the same subject as that of the main (independent) clause and a finitive verb form is changed to a non-finitive form.

> Yesterday the stock market crashed, which resulted in social collapse.

The subject of the relative clause headed by *which* is *which*. It refers to the "action of stock market's crashing yesterday" and that action resulted in social collapse. By eliding the subject *which* and changing the past tense form *resulted* to a non-finitive form (present participle) *resulting*, you can create a [*participle clause*](http://www.grammaring.com/participle-clauses).

> **Participle clauses replacing a relative clause**
>
> A present participle clause can replace an active voice finite
> relative clause. The noun before the participle is the doer of the
> action:
>
> If you think you have received an e-mail **containing** a virus, you should delete it immediately.
>
> (If you think you have received an e-mail **which contains** a virus, delete it immediately.)